# How to set a custom user agent in Cordova 5.0+ using Crosswalk 14+

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Can someone provide an example of how I could change the user agent in a cordova android application, using Crosswalk 14.43.343.23 and the cordova plugin crosswalk webview?

I have no idea how to get the settings in MainActivity and change the user agent. I know there is a `setUserAgentString` for the `XWalkView` , but how do I access the view?

Edit: I tried using `setUserAgentString` but I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setUserAgentString`

Comment: I got the same error in crosswalk 15.44.384.13.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
XWalkView xwalkView = (XWalkView) this.appView.getEngine().getView();
        try {
            Method ___getBridge = XWalkView.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBridge");
            ___getBridge.setAccessible(true);
            XWalkViewBridge xWalkViewBridge;
            xWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge) ___getBridge.invoke(xwalkView);
            XWalkSettings xWalkSettings = xWalkViewBridge.getSettings();
            xWalkSettings.setUserAgentString("");
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
```